# Can I make SSMTP to automatically set the "To:" header?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, ssmtp

I'm using the ssmtp package to send e-mail via g-mail. Everything is working fine with it - the only strange thing is that if I send mail via the command line, the "to field" is funky.

```
ssmtp me@domain.com < message.txt
```

Basically the "to" field will just say "undisclosed recipients"

I read that you can set headers containing a "To:" field, but that seems overly complicated when I've used the `mail` command on other systems, I it will do this automatically.

Is there an easier way to send mail via the command line with `ssmtp` - but without having to change the above syntax or specify additional parameters? (possibly a config file to set the "to" address as whatever one was specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This situation comes from a misunderstanding of what `ssmtp` is doing. There's a very important difference between the message **envelope** (which mail servers use for routing mail) and the message **body** (which is displayed in your e-mail client). Both may have `To` and `From`, and they may be different from each other. This is ***okay!***

`ssmtp` merely creates the envelope and facilitates transferring the message to the MTA. It expects the body you pass it to fully formed and *contain all body headers*. It will not add any for you*, (although it will insert message handling headers, e.g., `Received-by`, et al.). I'm sure you've also noticed that there is also no `Subject:` with those messages.

So the answer to your question is that the `To:` field needs to be included in `message.txt`.

To make the `To:` and `Subject:` fields show up you need to format `message.txt` like this:

```
To: cwd@gmail.com
Subject: Message for you

Message text starts here.
blah blah blah.
```

---

*That's not exactly true. Since a `From:` header is the only required header one will be derived from the envelope and inserted if it is missing.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that I didn't have to use `ssmtp` and I could use `mail` to do what I wanted having it actually use `ssmtp` to send the message.

Comment: ssmtp is for relaying to an external mail server so far as I understand.